# Linux описание модуля aesni-intel

Tags: linux, модули, ядро

Напишите команду как можно вывести описание модуля aesni_intel (description).
Мое решение:

## modinfo aesni_intel

Система не принимает

Comment: У меня данная команда без проблем выводит информацию по данному модулю, ядро 6.5.9, наличие модуля для конкретного ядра можно посмотреть по адресу  `/lib/modules/версия_ядра/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel.ko.zst` . Возможно в вашей версии ядра нету данного модуля.

Answer (score 0):

А `sudo` перед командой ? `sudo modinfo aesni_intel`